# Debugging: get path of execution

Tags: c#

I was wondering if there is any way to return the path that Visual Studio takes when running through a program. For example, without setting breakpoints, is it possible to know exactly what happens when I click a button on a web app I created? Like if I clicked a button that had an action, is there some kind of info that Visual Studio can spit out that tells me what happened? (which functions in which files were used, etc. Essentially the "code path").

To add on to my question, I'd like to use something like this to help debug an issue. I want to know exactly what is happening when I perform some kind of action (button click in my example). If I know every "code path" I can better address the issue I'm having.

Comment: You could use a performance profiler, which is designed to create these traces.

Comment: Do you have many different executions paths? Aren't you more interested to know why you're "there" than knowing execution path?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly your question, you're looking for [`Environment.StackTrace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.stacktrace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> The StackTrace property lists method calls in reverse chronological order, that is, the most recent method call is described first, and one line of stack trace information is listed for each method call on the stack. However, the StackTrace property might not report as many method calls as expected due to code transformations that occur during optimization.

Something else you can do is adding debug log entries to know what's is going on. It may be more useful since you could add extra custom data.

Not sure if you already have a log framework on your project. If you don't have any log4net could be a good option

Comment: ...except the OP wants to start tracing from the button click and see where the code goes, which is harder than dumping a stack trace from further down in the code (because the latter assumes you know beforehand what points are farther down on the execution path).

Comment: @adv12: it is true that you will have more data but requested path should be there. It's the easiest way I know to get that information.

Comment: @adv12: added another alternative: use a logging framework. I believe it would be the best since he can add extra data to understand why is following certain path.

Comment: I would go for AOP approach using interceptors - if you abstracted everything nicely behind interfaces, you can get a fairly good idea what's doing what by intercepting the interfaces with a logging aspect - and you keep the logging out of your code.

Comment: @ClaudioRedi: both of these suggestions involve *knowing the code path already*.  To get a stack trace that pertains to the button click, you would have to know that such and such a function is called as a result of the button click, so you can put code there to dump the stack trace.  Likewise with logging, you have to know which functions are on the execution path in order to insert logging in the right places.  The OP wants to *find* those places by *observing* which functions get called once he clicks the button.

Comment: @adv12: I may be biased by my experience, I find strange to be interested only on a execution path. I would be more interested to know why I'm there in case I reached a unexpected state (parameters values, methods return values, etc). I see application output and I know what's the execution path... the question is always "Why did I get there if I'm supposed to be there". So yes, I assume you know possible execution paths.

Answer (score 0):

Converting my comment to an answer so there is an answer that addresses the original question:

Use a performance profiler, which is designed to observe execution paths (typically to help you find bottlenecks, etc., but it will work fine for your purposes too).  A good performance profiler will let you dig down and see, for any method, what methods it calls, how frequently, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can print out a call stack results to the output window in Visual Studio. You will still need to use breakpoints but the ones that doesn't stop the application. To do that:

1. Find the place in your code when you would like to get the stack printed out. For instance at the end of button clicked handler.
2. Place a break point there.
3. Right click the breakpoint. From the context menu select "When Hit..." option.
4. In the window that will show up select "Print a message:" checkbox. It will enable a textbox. In the textbox type in: `$CALLSTACK`.
5. Check the "Continue execution" checkbox if you don't want to stop the execution while printing the results.

I don't remember if the "When Hit..." option is available in the Express edition of Visual Studio.

There are also some other data you can print out without breaking execution, e.g.: previous function, process id, etc. The details are actually available in the "When Hit..." window.